# JOOQ Issue: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jooq

I am using JOOQ 3.4.1 as middleware to communicate with Oracle Database but when I write the below Query in my code I got **SqlDataException:  AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required.**

```
select 0 prodid, cast(((cast('31-DEC-' as varchar2(4000)) || cast(YearForBilling as varchar2(4000))) || ' 12.59.00.000000000 PM ') as timestamp) theDate  0 Balance from ProductDetails where productRSN = 71 
group by YearForBilling
```

Can anybody help me out to fix that issue?

Answer (score 2):

#### Always try avoiding local date time formats

I would never rely on locale-dependent formatted date and timestamp strings. ***Never***. You never know if those settings change at some point of time, e.g. as the system default, or as a session setting, etc. Don't rely on it. ***Don't***.

If you can, use SQL standard timestamp literals that have absolutely no dependency on your `NLS` settings ([I've blogged about this here](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/09/15/dont-format-dates-in-sql-use-the-date-literal/)). For instance:

```
TIMESTAMP '2016-12-31 23:59:00.0'
```

In your case, you're creating a date dynamically, so timestamp literals won't work. But still, please use [ISO 8601 date formatting, as such](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(YearForBilling || '-12-31 23:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

The [`TO_TIMESTAMP()` function is described here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions229.htm).